# Jquery's $.parseJSON error fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the simple markup generated thru AJAX on the server. Relevant line is:

```
   <div id='login_history_resp' 
         class='paginator_slider' 
         DATA-params="{'SLIDER_LEFT_POS':139, 'SLIDER_WIDTH':309, 'HANDLE_WIDTH':165}" >
   </div>
```

The above is actually one line. I tried to break it into multiple for readability.
On this, I run the JS below and it fails.

```
   slider_css = $.parseJSON($('#login_history_resp').data('params'));
```

What did I try so far? I tried interchanging the double/single quotes in the string assigned to DATA-params. I tried taking the double-quotes out all together. I even tried .attr on DATA-params. I need to read it as an object and then extract individual properties. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Use double quotes and remove the `$.parseJSON`. jQuery handles it. http://jsfiddle.net/D37DR/

Comment: @BlackSheep Use double quotes where? I tried DATA-params='{"SLIDER...

Comment: For the properties, that's an invalid JSON. Also you shouldn't reparse it, jQuery calls the `$.parseJSON` behind the scene.

Comment: @BlackSheep Still not working. See comments below.

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle in my first comment. If it still doesn't work, reproducing the problem in a jsfiddle can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem was elsewhere. The id for the Div through AJAX was generating a # prefix but I did learn a few new things here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps here:

1. Change the quotes around your JSON properties to double quotes; it's [not valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/).
2. The `data` method will automatically parse your JSON, so no need!

The HTML:

```
<div id='login_history_resp' 
         class='paginator_slider' 
         DATA-params='{"SLIDER_LEFT_POS":139, "SLIDER_WIDTH":309, "HANDLE_WIDTH":165}' >
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
slider_css = $('#login_history_resp').data('params');
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried and it returns null. May be I am doing something wrong elsewhere in the AJAX returned. Let me check again. I have upvoted your answer. If the problem was elsewhere, I will certainly accept your answer. I did learn something anyway...

Comment: Evan Hahn. Problem was elsewhere. Thanks for your help. Answer accepted!